# What are the factors affecting torque (in normal cases)?

Tags: forces, mass, torque

I know that force and perpendicular displacement are the factors.

I want to know the factors like mass of the body and how and why is the force not distributed throughout the body uniformly.

According to my observations, if there is no mass, no turning would happen, am I correct?

Comment: $\tau=I\alpha$, I is the moment of inertia which is directly proportional to mass.

Comment: Are you asking a statics, mechanics of materials, or dynamics question. Are you interested in the affect of torque on stress and/or strain on a  mass, or on the motion of a mass. Please be clear.